# Interrupt camel route flow based on a condition

Tags: xml, apache-camel, routes

I have an application and two application servers. I deployed the same application to each of my application server but I also made them run as active-passive. To do this, I am using a lock.

Now I am coding my application with apache camel. In route, I want my code to be intercepted by a control which looks up a that if the lock released or not. According to the result, route will go on or not.

How can I do this with xml definition of camel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `<stop/>` tag you can use.

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>${bean:controller?method=isLocked} eq 'true'</simple>
        <stop/>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <to uri="direct:continueProcessing"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Comment: Thnx for the answer but I need it with xml. And in the example(that u have linked) , it does not give me what I want. I do not want to pause or stop a route. Just want a route to end that exact cycle. Not entire lifecycle of it

Comment: Aha, misunderstood your question. Now I have edited the answer to something that hopefully is more applicable.

Comment: Thanx Peter for this valuable info